# How to handle gherkin scenarios that have many steps in the 'then' stage

Tags: php, bdd, behat

They [say](https://automationpanda.com/2017/01/30/bdd-101-writing-good-gherkin/) that the cardinal rule of BDD is:

> One Scenario, One Behavior!

This is great, but the fact is that I got a single action that will trigger many different things in the system.. and I must verify *all of them* will happen. Here is my Gherkin:

```
Scenario: Buying a single product to be delivered now
    Given I am in the checkout page 
    When I checkout the order
    Then the order should be created to the specified address 
    And the order should be set in pending state
    And ops must be notified via a slack notification
    And A shopper must be auto assigned the order via a push notification
    And A retailer must be notified about the order via a push notification 
    And A transaction must be recorded in the payment gateway
    And My wallet should be deducted by the payment amount
```

This seems real ugly. But now I'm not sure how to separate it. Doing a **Background** doesn't seem to cut it since in a background, you are only setting up the groundwork for multiple scenarios where each scenario will have it's *when* and *then* pair  (In my case I'm using Behat, [which has](http://behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/writing_scenarios.html#backgrounds) a *given*, *when* and *then* in each scenario after a background).

Advice?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @Stratadox (split scenarios by behaviour) - `Given` step should never refer to the user interface or a stage in the user journey. The page the user is on is irrelevant to the business logic.

The `Given` step (like the `Arrange` step in unit testing) is used for setting the system up in a given state. This state set up in the `Given` step determines the outcome (the `Then` step)

For example:

"the order should be created to the specified address" - this outcome might have occurred as a consequence of the customer entering their address correctly (and in this case it might be necessary to specify actual the address so that it can be asserted in the `Then` step).

"My wallet should be deducted by the payment amount" - in order to assert that the system is in the correct state after charging your wallet, we'd probably check some kind of data persistence and we'd also check for a specific amount. What amount? Its the amount you specify in the `Given` step that is directly related to the outcome of this scenario

```
Scenario: Being charged the correct amount on successful purchase of product
   Given I have £10 in my wallet
   When I purchase a Toaster Oven for £4
   Then I should have £6 left in my wallet
```

"A shopper must be auto assigned the order via a push notification" - this is an outcome that can be asserted as part of a "successful purchase" check. The only thing it depends on is whether the purchase was successful or not. And you can bundle together the assertions like "shopper notified, retailer notified transaction recorded" - and give them one name, one line in your scenario e.g.:

```
Given Jon has the following items in his basket:
  | Macbook Pro | £3000 |
When Jon checks out his basket
Then a purchase of "xyz" for £3000 by Jon should have gone through
```

The last step here will imply doing three assertions under the hood. Which is fine as everyone know what's implied by a "purchase going through"

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way of tackling this, is by following the advice you quoted in your question:

> One Scenario, One Behavior!

To implement this advice, simply split the bloated scenario up in multiple smaller ones.

For instance:

```
Scenario: Buying a single product to be delivered now
    Given I am in the checkout page 
    When I checkout the order
    Then the order should be created to the specified address 
    And the order should be set in pending state

Scenario: Notifying ops of the purchase
    Given I am in the checkout page 
    When I checkout the order
    Then ops must be notified via a slack notification
```

...etc.

Many of the `given`'s in your scenario aren't very much related to each other. They have some temporal relationship, because they all happen to happen right after an order was placed, but that's all.

You could even go a step further and consider grouping them as different features.

After all, notifying ops is a different *feature* from processing payments, which in turn is different form stock calculations.